# npm global install links to wrong directory

Tags: node.js, npm, debian-jessie

I am using an installation of nodejs, as described [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).

When I run this: `# npm install -g markdown-pdf`

I receive the following error:

```
(PhantomJS is a Requirement for markdown-pdf):
Phantom installation failed { Error: EACCES: permission denied, link 
'/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-
1507729380912/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/markdown-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs-
prebuilt/lib/phantom'
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'link',
path: '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-
1507729380912/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64',
dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/markdown-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs-
prebuilt/lib/phantom' } Error: EACCES: permission denied, link 
'/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-
1507729380912/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/markdown-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs-
prebuilt/lib/phantom'
```

As one can see, the error occurs when trying to link to `/usr/lib/node_modules/markdown-pdf`

However, the actual `node_modules` (containing actual modules) folder is located at `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules`

Root is the only user on the System (debian-jessie), therefore permissions should not be a problem. I tried [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) (which also includes the option of creating a global directory manually), but to no avail. I would like it very much to keep it all in one (global) directory.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Got it fixed. Sort of.

Re-Installed nodejs

Set NODE_PATH (which was empty) to `/usr/lib/node_modules`

Used `sudo npm install -g markdown-pdf --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` (see [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268))